Why can't i delete iteration from the board?
I use a powershell script to call the azure rest api and add new iterations and delete the three basic iteration.
For the api it work, if i get the list of iterations Iteration 1 to 3 are deleted, however if i go to the GUI there are still here :
Did i miss something ?
Code
function deleteIteration {
    [CmdletBinding()] param ( 
        [Parameter( Mandatory )] [string]    $organization,
        [Parameter( Mandatory )] [string]    $project,
        [Parameter( Mandatory )] [string]    $iteration,
        [Parameter( Mandatory )] [hashtable] $header
    )

    try {

        [string] $team        = getMainTeamName -organization $organization -project $project
        [string] $iterationId = getIterationId -organization $organization -project $project -iteration $iteration -team $team -header $header
        [string] $uri         = "$url/{0}/{1}/{2}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/{3}?{4}" -f $organization, $project, $team, $iterationId, $apiVersion
        [Object] $query       = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Delete -Headers $header

        Write-Host "- Iteration $iteration has been deleted !"

    } catch {
        Write-Host "##[error] An error occurred while deleting Iteration $name at $uri."
        Get-Error
        throw
    }
}


Can you share the current PowerShell script sample with us? This will be helpful to figure out the issue in the script.

I'll do that in the main post.

Thanks for your update. I will check the issue.

Based on your screenshot and powershell script, you need to delete the iteration at the project level. You need to change to use this Rest api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/classification-nodes/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP#delete-an-iteration-node For more detailed info, you can refer to my answer.

From your screenshot, you need to delete the iteration in the Project Settings -> Project Configuration -> Itertaions (Project Level).
For example:

When you use the Rest API：Iterations - Delete， it will delete the iteration at Team level(Project Settings -> Team Configuration -> Itertaions).
For example:

It will not delete the iteration at the Project Level.
To solve this issue, you need change to use the Rest API: Classification Nodes - Delete
DELETE https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/classificationnodes/{structureGroup}/{path}?api-version=5.1

structureGroup: iterations
path: Iteration name(e.g. Iteration 1, Iteration 2,Iteration 3)
For example:
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/classificationnodes/iterations/Iteration 1?api-version=5.1

Then it will delete the iteration at project level.
